# Swift: Modifying date via date components

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I have a dateTime which is 06:59:59am. I wish to change it to 7:00:00am.

Eg: When I print a dateTime object - "2022-10-27 06:59:59 +0000 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 688546799.0"

To get time as 07:00:00, I tried "`Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: dateTime)`" and the output I get is "`2022-10-27 07:00:59 +0000 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 688546859.0`"

How can I change the seconds to 00 instead of 59, so I can get 07:00:00 instead of 07:00:59?

Comment: have you tried `.second` instead of `.minute`? Or alternatively, `Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: -59, to: dateTime)`

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateString = "06:59:29am"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale     = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ssa"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

let timeInterval = date?.timeIntervalSince1970
let rounded = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (timeInterval! / 60.0).rounded(.toNearestOrEven) * 60.0)
print(rounded)
```

This will round ur time to the nearest minute. In case f u want to nearest 2 minutes instead of 60.0 use 120.0 and accordingly.